# Limitations with Xbox 360 edition of Minecraft? (Quartz ore and Infinity enchantment)

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I can't find a single block of quartz ore in the Nether and after enchanting around 50 of my items and checking every time, I was never offered the Infinity enchantment for the bow (I'm always level 30 or higher and have over 15 bookshelves around my enchantment table).

Has this ever happened to anyone or does anybody if there is an history of these types of problems on the 360?

Except starting another world, is there a solution?